# preg_match_all question about number

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have this line:

```
preg_match_all("/<data_[0-9]>(.*?)<\/data_[0-9]>/",$xml_report,$xml);
```

and for some reason he takes me only the 10 first rows 0 until 9 but he didn't take the 10+ rows..

what I need to change the [0-9] ?

Comment: *(tip)* use an [XML parser](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) when dealing with XML.

Comment: @Gordon this mundane task is fine with Regex, it's very simple, XML parsing would be better for expandibility, but for simply getting the contents of `<data_[0-9]+></data_[0-9]+>`, regex is perfect.

Comment: @Korvin IMO that depends on how the contents are going to be processed. If there is more XML inside, then I'd say dont do it with Regex. If not then yes, Regex is okay indeed. Then again, depending on the XML structure, using SimpleXML would be equally easy to use for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[0-9]` selects only one occurrence of the numbers 0-9. Use `[0-9]+`

The `+` means one or more of the preceding element vs `*` or `.` which is zero or more.

Comment: It you want to be limit the number to 999 for some reason, you would go with [0-9]{1,3} . The answer [0-9]+ is equal to [0-9]{1,}

Comment: I simply pointed it out since he uses (.*?) without seeming to know exactly how * and + operates. Therefor not supplying it as an answer, just a comment :)

Comment: That is very valid, yet I explained how `*`, `+` and `.` operate. Therefore, it is a valid thing to supply for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you append `+` (plus) after `]` it'll find for multiple occurences

```
preg_match_all("/<data_[0-9]+>(.*?)<\/data_[0-9]+>/",$xml_report,$xml);
```

Comment: flagged down because you forgot the last [0-9]

Answer (score 0):

You only check for one occurence of the number, try this:

```
preg_match_all("/<data_[0-9]+>(.*?)<\/data_[0-9]+>/",$xml_report,$xml);
```